# Processing js not working in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, processing

I am using Processing JS in a Google Chrome Extension. The regular webpage works, but when I try in an extension, the following shows up:

```
window.localStorage is not available in packaged apps. Use chrome.storage.local instead. extensions::platformApp:17

processing.js:718 Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
processing.js:798 Processing.js: Unable to execute pjs sketch.
processing.js:799 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
```

is there some way around this?

Comment: Can you get around your issue using [p5.js](http://p5js.org/) for the Processing functionalities and plain js to get around some of the limitations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You cannot relax the [default CSP of Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy) to allow `eval`, and you can't get `localStorage` to work, it is [disabled](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated) and `chrome.storage` is asynchronous, therefore you can't make a polyfill.

Unless Processing makes a version that's compatible with Chrome Apps platform, or you make extensive modifications to it, it's not possible to work around.

Comment: Thanks. Why does Processing.js use localstorage, anyway?